# how to get the path and file name of a uploaded file in Zend framework

Tags: php, zend-framework, zend-file

I have form which allow users to upload a file. From my controller I want to get the path with filename. I am using getFileName() method. But it gives the below error:

```
Message: Method getFileName does not exist
```

Below is my controller action:

```
public function addAction()
    {
        $form = new Application_Form_Student();
        $form->setAttrib('enctype', 'multipart/form-data');
        $form->submit->setLabel('Add');
        $this->view->form = $form;

        if ($this->getRequest()->isPost()) {
            $formData = $this->getRequest()->getPost();
            if ($form->isValid($formData)) {
                $name = $form->getValue('name');
                $email = $form->getValue('email');
                $photo = $form->getValue('photo');
                $location = $form->getFileName('photo'); 
                $students = new Application_Model_DbTable_Students();
                $students->addStudent($name, $email);

                $this->_helper->redirector('index');
            } else {
                $form->populate($formData);
            }
        }

    }
```

Comment: If the file is uploaded successfully, it should be in the TEMP folder if you yourself have not provided any path otherwise the uploaded file will be present in the folder specified by you, and the name of file would not change

Comment: @Joddy I have provided the path in form class. But I want to get it from my controller. 
what is the meaning of the error
Message: Method getFileName does not exist

Comment: getFileName  is not a valid FORM OBJECT METHOD, you need to call that on a Zend File Transfer Adapter Http OBJECT not FORM OBJECT

Comment: use  Zend_File_Transfer_Adapter_Http()
check out if that works for you, or setup your Zend_Form_Element_File properly. that will work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check if this works -

```
public function addAction()
{
    $form = new Application_Form_Student();
    $form->setAttrib('enctype', 'multipart/form-data');
    $form->submit->setLabel('Add');
    $this->view->form = $form;

    if ($this->getRequest()->isPost()) {
        $formData = $this->getRequest()->getPost();
        if ($form->isValid($formData)) {
            $upload = new Zend_File_Transfer_Adapter_Http();
            $upload->setDestination("/uploads/files/");


            try { 
                 $upload->receive();
                 $location = $upload->getFileName('photo');
            }                
            catch(Zend_File_Transfer_Exception $e){
                 $e->getMessage();
            }
        } else {
            $form->populate($formData);
        }
    }

}
```

The Second Method I was talking about. FORM FILE ELEMENT Settings
    [Zend Framework: Upload file by using Zend Form Element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6733819/zend-framework-upload-file-by-using-zend-form-element)

Comment: can you please tell me how to get only file name instead of path