# BOX-API upload file form

Tags: file-upload, box-api

i'm trying to upload a file in BOX_API with php and Zend framework. But i'm missing somethin. It's the first time that i use an interface like this o i've read the [manual](http://developers.box.com/docs/#files-upload-a-file). But it is confusig for me. My question are two:

-First, why do you have to pass to the post call only the name of the file and not the whole file with the right header for file upload? File upload in a form is not like passing the name of the file through a post call;

-secondly and consequently, do i have to make a form for file upload or simply a textarea where to write the name of the file to be passed to the BOX-API?

UPDATE:
This is the code of my upload form:

```
    $form = new Zend_Form;
    $form->setAction('/imball-reagens/public/upload')
    ->setMethod('post');
    $file = new Zend_Form_Element_File('file');
    $file->setLabel('Choose a file to upload:');
    $file->addValidator('alnum');
    $file->setRequired(true);
    $form->addElement($file);
    $access_token = new Zend_Form_Element_Hidden(array('name' => 'access_token', 'value' => $result->access_token));
    $form->addElement($access_token);
    $refresh_token = new Zend_Form_Element_Hidden(array('name' => 'refresh_token', 'value' => $result->refresh_token));
    $form->addElement($refresh_token);
    $form->addElement('submit', 'upload', array('label' => 'Upload File'));
    echo $form;
```

And this s the POST cal to the box API which comes after the form:

```
    $access_token= $this->getRequest()->getParam('access_token');
    $client = new Zend_Http_Client('https://upload.box.com/api/2.0/files/content');
    $client->setMethod(Zend_Http_Client::POST);
    $client->setHeaders('Authorization: Bearer '.$access_token);
    $data = $_FILES["file"]["name"];
    $client->setParameterPost(array(
            'filename'  => '@'.$data,
            'parent_id' => '0'
    ));
    $response = $client->request()->getBody();
    $this->view->response= $response;
    $result = json_decode($response);
```

The error it throws is below:

```
 {"type":"error","status":400,"code":"invalid_request_parameters","help_url":"http:\/\/developers.box.com\/docs\/#errors","message":"Invalid input parameters in request","request_id":"172518183652dcf2a16af73"}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tricky to debug without seeing all of the code, but in the bit you pasted it looks like you are passing `$_FILES["file"]["name"]` to the API - this only contains the original name of the file which was uploaded by the user - you need to pass the location to the file on the server which is sending the data to the Box API client so that it can grab it and send it to the Box server - this should be stored in `$_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"]`.

I would recommend changing the code to this and trying again:

```
$access_token= $this->getRequest()->getParam('access_token');
$client = new Zend_Http_Client('https://upload.box.com/api/2.0/files/content');
$client->setMethod(Zend_Http_Client::POST);
$client->setHeaders('Authorization: Bearer '.$access_token);
$data = $_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"];
$client->setParameterPost(array(
    'parent_id' => '0'
));
$client->setFileUpload($data, 'filename');
$response = $client->request()->getBody();
$this->view->response= $response;
$result = json_decode($response);
```

Comment: I've tryied it but the response is always the same error. I guess i'll have to check the others parameters too. thank you anyway for your answer!

Comment: Is it possible that the error is just in the URL line? should i write "http" or "https"?

Comment: Strange, maybe save the file somewhere first with `move_uploaded_file` - http://uk1.php.net/move_uploaded_file and then give the filename and path to the Box API? I think the Box API requires HTTPS. Also, I would check how you're getting your access token, perhaps the error is there instead.

Comment: Tryied, it moves the file to the new path but it throws anyway the same error, are you sure it is a problem of the access token? I'm using the same call of the access token to retrieve the item from the folder of the BOX_API but it doesn't seem to cause problems there. Do you notice anything wrong with this call except from the possible wrong access token?

Comment: I think maybe the Zend http client takes the upload a bit differently - try this gist https://gist.github.com/madebydavid/8541566

Comment: i think this ´$client->setFileUpload($data, 'filename');` line is not working cause in the box-api documentation says the filename has to have an @ in front of the filename but if I place an @ in front of the file name in thet line the file is not retrieved from the system! How can i do to solve this problem?

Comment: The Box API does not need the `@` sign - the `@` syntax is just for curl - it is so that curl knows that whatever follows the `@` sign is a filename. For the Zend client, you have the `setFileUpload` function - so you do not need an `@` sign.